# How to run systemctl enable xxx during docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I hope this question finds you all well.

I am currently trying to create a Docker container image and I am facing a problem.
  My original idea for the Dockerfile was the following:

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

And saving this as a base image using `docker build -t baseimage .`. So far so good.

The application's installer is a .run which among other things executes something like `systemctl start xxx.service` (I cannot change that and the installation will fail if this part fails).

I have already tried some things for the second Dockerfile, such as:

```
FROM baseimage
...
COPY xxx.run xxx.run
RUN ./xxx.run # This return an error like "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted"
...
```

and changing the original CMD to run this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
/usr/sbin/init # With and without & after this one
./xxx.run
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run this application in a virtual machine instead?  Systemd is pretty unsuited to running in Docker, and if the installer expects to `systemctl start` something, it's going to be very tricky to make that happen while Systemd is running.

Answer (score 1):

The case of using an installer for a non-dockerized application in a docker container ... is one of the achievements that work with the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement).

Answer (score 0):

Your build is trying to do a privileged operation. The issue is, `--privileged` flag is unavailable at build time. Here's the issue, which makes an interesting reading : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916

TL;DR there seems to be two possibilities with docker itself

- Enable experimental mode then `RUN --security=insecure ./xxx.run`, as documented here https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---securityinsecuresandbox
- Install buildx cli plugin, then `docker buildx build --allow security.insecure`, as documented here https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/master/README.md#--allowentitlement

Other solution outside docker would be to use `buildah`, but that's a longer shot by far. But an interesting one, especially if you works in the RedHat ecosystem, since they want to get rid of Docker in favor of Buildah/Podman. Here's the [get started](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/master/docs/tutorials/01-intro.md). Though I'm not clear about how it solve your issue, it's been highlighted as being able to deal with this kind of issues.